# What do we need when running the software with the MySQL database on the user computer?

Tags: c#, mysql

I created an application with a C # programming language and MySQL database.
When I want to install the software on the user's computer,
What software do I need?
MySQL software should be fully installed on the user's system?
Or is there another way?

Comment: There are a myriad of possible installer/deployment options. You need to specify what the requirements are (MySQL DBs can, of course, be accessed across a network...)

Comment: You created the application. Does it need to access the database locally, or a network instance somewhere? What does your app require?

Comment: So you want the app to run on Windows? And wondering how to bundle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this with a stand-alone database, or are you creating a shared database the client application needs to connect to?

If it's a stand-alone program then **don't use MySQL**. Use an embeddable database library like [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/) instead. These are far more durable and resilient and can handle abrupt shutdowns and restarts. MySQL needs a lot more care and attention, plus has a huge footprint in terms of memory and CPU consumption. Managing that automatically is not easy. Walking a client through how to repair a damaged MySQL database is not something you want to do.

If it's a shared database then you technically only need the client libraries, but remember, **exposing MySQL to the general internet is extremely dangerous** and should be avoided whenever possible. If you must, ensure that your users are using SSH or a VPN of some sort for access to restrict who can connect to your database server.

The best plan for a remote application is to build out an API that intermediates between client and database, giving you the ability to layer in access control at every level necessary to protect the data. MySQL has very broad access control, locking down individual records can be hard to do and easy to get wrong. Unless you can trust *all* users, it's best to not trust *any*.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the server installation on the client / remote machine. Just a workbench should be fine through which you can connect to the server and perform any database operations.

Comment: Thank you very much